# Insert missing rows in time series data

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp

I have an incomplete time series dataframe and I need to insert rows of NAs for missing time stamps. There should always be 6 time stamps per day, which is indicated by the variable "Signal" (1-6) in the dataframe. I am trying to merge the incomplete dataframe `A` with a vector `B`containing all Signals. Simplified example data below:

```
B <- rep(1:6,2) 
A <- data.frame(Signal = c(1,2,3,5,1,2,4,5,6), var1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
Expected <- data.frame(Signal = c(1,2,3,NA, 5, NA, 1,2,NA,4,5,6), var1 = c(1,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,1,1)
```

Note that `B`represents a dataframe with multiple variables and the NAs in `Expected` are rows of NAs in the dataframe. Also the actual dataframe has more observations (84 in total).

Would be awesome if you guys could help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know there are 6 timestamps in a day you can do this without `B`. We can create groups for each day and use `complete` to add the missing observations with `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

A %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Signal) < 0))) %>%
  complete(Signal = 1:6) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr)

#   Signal  var1
#    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1     1
# 2      2     1
# 3      3     1
# 4      4    NA
# 5      5     1
# 6      6    NA
# 7      1     1
# 8      2     1
# 9      3    NA
#10      4     1
#11      5     1
#12      6     1
```

If in the output you need `Signal` as `NA` for missing combination you can use

```
A %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Signal) < 0))) %>%
  complete(Signal = 1:6) %>%
  mutate(Signal = replace(Signal, is.na(var1), NA)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-gr)

#   Signal  var1
#    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1     1
# 2      2     1
# 3      3     1
# 4     NA    NA
# 5      5     1
# 6     NA    NA
# 7      1     1
# 8      2     1
# 9     NA    NA
#10      4     1
#11      5     1
#12      6     1
```

Comment: You just saved me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you explain to me what exactly the code you posted does in detail. It works and I am grateful, but I don't really understand what it does.

Comment: @BjörnButter `group_by` creates groups for every sequence until a lower number is observed. So 1, 2, 3 and 5 becomes one group, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 becomes another group. Now within each group we complete the sequence from `1:6` which means it will add the number which is missing from `1:6` and add `NA` to other columns. So in first group it adds 4 and 6 as they are missing and so on for other groups.

Comment: One more question: why is there the TRUE at the beginning of c(TRUE,...)?

Comment: Because `diff` returns output of length 1 less than the original vector so we append `TRUE` at the begining.